# Showing div content based on last array element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a page which has numerous hidden divs on the page.  When the user clicks on a particular button, the page associate with that button appears and the id is added to an array.  This aspect of the program works the way it should, the problem I'm having is that, I would also like for the previous div to be hidden.  Also, when a user clicks on a back button, I would like for the id to be removed from the array(also works) and that div hidden again and the previous one to show back up.  So basically, how do I hide the previous div elements while showing the next div elements(These elements are added to the array) and vice-versa?  I know this is not very well asked, but I'm adding my code with comments and screenshots to kinda help out with the narrative of the question.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <header>
            <div id="ribbon"></div>
            <hgroup>
                <h3>Gulfstream G-IV</h3>
                <h2>FlightSafety Versatile Tutor</h2>
            </hgroup>
        </header>

        <div id="home_page" class="page">
            <button class="button" id="check_btn">Functional Checks</button>
        </div>

        <div id="check_page">
            <h1>G-IV Functional Checks</h1>
            <div class="half">
                <button class="button" id="integrity_check_btn">Battery Integrity Check</button>
                <button class="button">Pressurization System Check</button>
                <button class="button">Fuel System Check</button>
                <button class="button">Oxygen Crew Mask / Regulator Preflight Test</button>
                <button class="button">Cockpit Voice Recorder(CVR) Test</button>
                <button class="button">Display Controller Test</button>
            </div>
            <div class="half">
                <button class="button">Flight Guide Panel Test</button>
                <button class="button">Auxiliary Hydraulic Pump/ Brake System Check</button>
                <button class="button">Elevator Trim System Check</button>
                <button class="button">Ground Spoiler System Check</button>
                <button class="button">Stall Warning/ Stall Barrier System Check</button>
                <button class="button">APU Overspeed or ASC 465 ECU BIT Test</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="integrity_check_page">
            <h1>Battery Integrity Check</h1>
            <div class="full">
                <button class="button" id="question">When is the check Conducted?</button>
                <button class="button" id="answer_vid">Video:  Check Conducted at Normal Pace</button>
                <button class="button" id="explain_vid">Video:  Functional Check Explained</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="return">
            <div id="return_btn"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var id;
    var parent;
    var history = [];

    $(this).find("div").each(function(){
        id = $(this).prop("id");
        if(id == ""){
            *//Removes divs without ids from array*
            history.pop(id);
        }
    })

    history.push("home_page");
    console.log(history);

    $("button").on("click touchstart", function(){
        *//Replaces the button designator and adds the page designator to find the div associated with the button.*
        id = $(this).prop("id").replace("_btn", "_page");
        var h1 = $("#" +id +" h1").text();
        *//Shows the div associated with the clicked button*
        $("#" +id).show();
        *//Shows the back button*
        $(".return").show();
        *//Appends the h1 text to the hgroup*
        $("hgroup").append("<h1>" +h1 +"</h1>");
        *//Adds the div associated with the clicked button to the array*
        history.push(id);
        console.log(history);
    })

    $(".return").on("click touchstart", function(){
        *//If the array has less than two elements, hides the back button*
        if(history.length <= 2){
            $(".return").hide();
        }
        *//Hides the h1 text*
        $("h1").hide();
        *//Hides the div*
        $("#" +id).hide();
        *//Removes the last div from the array*
        history.pop(id);
        console.log(history);
    })
})
```

**Splash Page**
[image: Splash Page]

**User clicks Function Check Button, previous div & h1 not hiding**
[image: Functional Checks Button Clicked]

**User clicks Battery Integrity Check Button, same result**
[image: Battery Integrity Check Button Clicked]

**User clicks Back Button, last div is hidden & all h1 elements are hidden**
[image: Back Button Clicked]

**Back Button clicked again, but last div is not being hidden**
[image: Back Button Clicked]

**Console log goes along with the images above**
[image: Console]

Comment: If possible , can post `html` ? Thanks

Comment: I actually got it figured out, so I'm going to post what I have as an answer, but yes I will post the HTML as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got it working.  But if anyone has a better way of doing this, please post as an answer as well.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <header>
            <div id="ribbon"></div>
            <hgroup>
                <h3>Gulfstream G-IV</h3>
                <h2>FlightSafety Versatile Tutor</h2>
                <h1 id="title"></h1>
            </hgroup>
        </header>

        <div id="home_page" class="page">
            <button class="button" id="check_btn">Functional Checks</button>
        </div>

        <div id="check_page" class="page">
            <h1>G-IV Functional Checks</h1>
            <div class="half">
                <button class="button" id="integrity_check_btn">Battery Integrity Check</button>
                <button class="button">Pressurization System Check</button>
                <button class="button">Fuel System Check</button>
                <button class="button">Oxygen Crew Mask / Regulator Preflight Test</button>
                <button class="button">Cockpit Voice Recorder(CVR) Test</button>
                <button class="button">Display Controller Test</button>
            </div>
            <div class="half">
                <button class="button">Flight Guide Panel Test</button>
                <button class="button">Auxiliary Hydraulic Pump/ Brake System Check</button>
                <button class="button">Elevator Trim System Check</button>
                <button class="button">Ground Spoiler System Check</button>
                <button class="button">Stall Warning/ Stall Barrier System Check</button>
                <button class="button">APU Overspeed or ASC 465 ECU BIT Test</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="integrity_check_page" class="page">
            <h1>Battery Integrity Check</h1>
            <div class="full">
                <button class="button" id="question">When is the check Conducted?</button>
                <button class="button" id="answer_vid">Video:  Check Conducted at Normal Pace</button>
                <button class="button" id="explain_vid">Video:  Functional Check Explained</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="return">
            <div id="return_btn"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var id;
    var parent;
    var history = [];

    $(this).find("div").each(function(){
        id = $(this).prop("id");
        if(id == ""){
            //Removes divs without ids from array
            history.pop(id);
        }
    })

    history.push("home_page");

    $("button").on("click touchstart", function(){
        //Replaces the button designator and adds the page designator to find the div associated with the button.
        id = $(this).prop("id").replace("_btn", "_page");
        var h1 = $("#" +id +" h1").text();
        $(this).parents(".page").hide();
        if($(this).parents(".page").prop("id") !== "check_page"){
            var title = $(this).text();
            $(this).parents(".page").find("h1").html(title);
        }

        //Shows the div associated with the clicked button
        $("#" +id).show();
        //Shows the back button
        $(".return").show();
        //Adds the div associated with the clicked button to the array
        history.push(id);
    })

    $(".return").on("click touchstart", function(){
        var last = history[history.length - 2];
        var current = history[history.length - 1];
        //If the array has less than two elements, hides the back button
        if(history.length <= 2){
            $(".return").hide();
        }
        $("#" +last).show();
        //Hides the div
        $("#" +current).hide();
        //Removes the last div from the array
        history.pop(id);
    })
```